# Why is the method "save" from the spring data jpa not working?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Here is my item_table from Postgress:

| item_id, int NotNull | price, double | item_name, varchar (50) | date, date | user_id, int, foreign key | category_id, int, foreign key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

My entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"item_table\"")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="item_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="item_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Name must not be empty")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="price")
    @NotNull(message = "Price must not be null")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Price should be be greater then zero")
    private double price;
    @JoinColumn(name="\"category_id\"")
    @OneToOne
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "Category must not be null")
    private Category category;
    @JoinColumn(name="\"user_id\"")
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    @Column(name="date")
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "Date must not be null")
    private Date date;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {
    
    List<Item> findByUserId(int userId);

    List<Item> findByUserIdAndCategoryId(int userId, int categoryId);

}
```

Service  methods are:

```
@Override
    public Item saveItem(Item item, String userToken) {
        item.setUser(userService.getUserFromToken(userToken));
        Item savedItem = itemRepository.save(item);
        return savedItem;
    }
@Override
    public List<Item> saveAllItems(List<Item> items) {
        return itemRepository.saveAll(items);
    }
```

And Controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveItem(@Valid @ModelAttribute("item") @RequestBody Item item,
            @RequestHeader("Authorization") String userToken) {
        log.info("Handling save item: " + item);
        Item addedItem =  itemService.saveItem(item, userToken.substring(7));
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(addedItem.getId())
                .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveAllItems(@RequestBody List<Item> items) {
        log.info("Handling save items");
        itemService.saveAllItems(items);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

The problem is: when I'm using "saveAll()" method I send the whole entity information in the request body. For saving a single item in "save()", I send data without a user object, which is inserted later from the user token in the Service layer. The typical request body in this request looks like this:

```
{
    "item_name": "Pizza",
    "price": 13,
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00.000+00:00",
    "category": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Food"
    }
}
```

By investigating the logs I noticed that hibernate tries to save the entities data, but all of the fields are null, which causes a Validation exception as shown below:

```
JPATraversableResolver       : Calling isReachable on object Item(id=0, name=null, price=0.0, category=null, user=null, date=null) with node name price.
```

So what is wrong with this code that it is showing nulls from the tables when it tries to save the data?

Comment: Your controller doesn't make sense, either use `@ModelAttribute` (for binding request parameters like from a HTML form) or use `@RequestBody`. Using both on a single argument doesn't make any sense (and is probably the cause of your issues).

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you.